# Why doesn't MSVC optimize cout for char or const char* but it does for int?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Compare the codes:

```
    const char x = 'a';
    std::cout<< x;
00C31000  mov         eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0C32054h)]  
00C31005  push        eax  
00C31006  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0C310B0h)  
00C3100B  add         esp,4
```

and

```
    const int x = 'a';
    std::cout<< x;
00271000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (272048h)]  
00271006  push        61h  
00271008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (272044h)]
```

and

```
    const char* x = "a";
    std::cout<< x;
00071000  mov         eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (72058h)]  
00071005  push        eax  
00071006  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (710B0h)  
0007100B  add         esp,4
```

<del>It seems that the `const int` version is better optimized than the `const char*` and the (even more surprising)`const char` version.</del> **The question - Why is there a difference in the generated code?**

Comment: Did you try const char* const?

Comment: what version of VS are you using? Out of curiosity

Comment: @bamboon: Wouldn't make a difference, the last `const` does not affect the overload chosen. (There's no `const char*&` in the overload set).

Comment: Why are you so sure that the const int version is better optimized?  Doesn't this really depend on what the actual function calls do?

Comment: I agree- I don't see what "optimization" you mean.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it almost looks like `const int` is optimized all the way to a `constexpr` and everything is completely thrown out to just the value. Is that what you're pondering?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore rare i'm actually on the same-page this early in one of your questions. And you're not alone; i'm genuinely curious as well. =P

Comment: Looks like part of an assembly is missing in 1 and 3 samples. I see only one argument pushed in stack. That should be another one.

Comment: @Lol4t0 nope, that's the whole thing.

Comment: @Lol4t0 What argument are you missing?

Comment: @Gorpik, `std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >` is a free function. It means, 2 arguments should be supplied. Arguments are passed through the stack. We see in sample only one `push`. It means, we see only one argument. (That is stream itself). Before this line it should be another `push`, that is value of x

Comment: Luchian Grigore, since those adds come after the function call, I feel like they arent directly related to the call itself, and thus shouldnt be part of the question?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, [that is](http://pastebin.com/e8Fpcnjj) the actual code fore char version

Comment: @Lol4t0: not all arguments must be on the stack, it might be that the stream param goes in a registeer, and the stream pointer was already in the correct register for this code.

Comment: @MooingDuck, `cdecl` calling conversion insists that all arguments should be supplied through the stack. That is.

Comment: @Lol4t0: It appears that this case is using cdecl, I was merely observing that not only is cdecl not required in the spec, but that compilers can and do cheat even for cdecl functions. (forr instance, inlining)

Comment: @MooingDuck, of cause they could inline, but we see here `call` and we see part of `cdecl` and complete `thiscall` for 2nd example. Compiler cannot partially cheat, it should either inline (and it means it wouldn't be `call`), or pass all arguments according to the calling conversion. If compiler will omit some parameters, function will break stack when unwinding it on return. `MSVS` uses `cdecl` or `thiscall` by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some overloads of `operator<<` (including for `int`, but *not* `char` or `const char*`) are members of `std::ostream`; some are non-member functions taking `std::ostream&` as their first parameter.

Microsoft's compiler uses different calling conventions for member and non-member functions. I'm guessing that you're building for 32-bit Windows. In that case member functions will use the `thiscall` convention, where `this` is passed in register `ecx` and the remaining arguments are passed on the stack; and non-member functions use the `cdecl` convention, where all arguments are passed on the stack.

Comment: Is it specified which are members and which are not?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, in C++11 27.7.3.6.2 (and the definition of `basic_ostream` in 27.7.3.1). The member is overloaded for all arithmetic types except (signed or unsigned) `char` and `charT`, and also for `const void*`.

Comment: Why isn't it overloaded for signed/unsigned `char`?

Comment: @Dave: I'm guessing the reason for overloading them as non-members has something to do with the overload selection rules (avoiding ambiguity, or forcing a particular choice of "best" overload), but I've no idea exactly what that reason might be.

Answer (score 1):

From the operator names: because one is a member and the other is a free function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, and calling conversions are differ.